# How to return true or false if user info matches the database info?

Tags: php, android

I want to make a php file to return true or false on the android device if the user's info (login info) has match the info that are stored in database.

I have written the code below so far :

```
<?php

require "init.php";

if($connection){

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT * FROM  `admin` WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);


    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For return a json you have to make an associative array and encode it to json.

```
<?php
require "init.php";
require "init.php";

if($connection){
  $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];

 $statement = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT * FROM  `admin` WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);

if(mysqli_stmt_execute($statement)){
   $response=array('response'=>true);
 }else {
   $response=array('response'=>false);
  }
   echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);


 mysqli_close($connection);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mysqli_stmt_execute return a boolean just print the result or you can make a json.

```
<?php
    require "init.php";
    require "init.php";

    if($connection){
      $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];

   $statement = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT * FROM  `admin` WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);
   if(mysqli_stmt_execute($statement)){
       echo "true";
     }else {
       echo "false";
      }

   mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);


  mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i see..how can i make a JSON to store that boolean?